# Postgresql slow match by ILIKE ANY

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to calculate intersection between `trade_name` column in a `grls_data` table and `data ->> 'product_info'` in `fsa_raw` table by substring matching.

Value count in the tables:

1. `grls`: 38596
2. `grls_data`: 47434
3. `fsa_raw`: 651380

I have a following SQL schema:

```
CREATE TABLE public.grls
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('grls_id_seq'::regclass),
  use_version integer,
  CONSTRAINT grls_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT grls_use_version_foreign FOREIGN KEY (use_version)
      REFERENCES public.grls_data (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);

CREATE INDEX grls_use_version_index
  ON public.grls
  USING btree
  (use_version);

CREATE TABLE public.grls_data
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('grls_data_id_seq'::regclass),
  grls_id integer NOT NULL,
  trade_name text NOT NULL,
  // other columns
  CONSTRAINT grls_data_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT grls_data_grls_id_foreign FOREIGN KEY (grls_id)
      REFERENCES public.grls (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);

CREATE INDEX grls_data_grls_id_index
  ON public.grls_data
  USING btree
  (grls_id);


CREATE INDEX grls_data_trade_name_index
  ON public.grls_data
  USING hash
  (trade_name COLLATE pg_catalog."default");

CREATE TABLE public.fsa_raw
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('fsa_raw_id_seq'::regclass),
  data jsonb,
  CONSTRAINT fsa_raw_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);

CREATE INDEX fsa_raw_data_idx
  ON public.fsa_raw
  USING gin
  (data jsonb_path_ops);

CREATE INDEX words_trgm_gin
  ON public.fsa_raw
  USING gin
  ((data ->> 'product_info'::text) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" gin_trgm_ops);
```

So, i wrote a following SQL query for test:

```
WITH tns AS (
   SELECT DISTINCT ('%' || trade_name || '%') AS tn FROM grls JOIN grls_data ON
   grls.use_version = grls_data.id
)
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fsa_raw
WHERE (data ->> 'product_info') ILIKE ANY (SELECT tn FROM tns)
```

But my query have a really giant cost:

> Aggregate (cost=169494199.21..169494199.22 rows=1 width=8)

I can't wait for weeks, months to get query results.
How do i optimize my SQL-query to get results much faster?

Comment: i doubt you can make it gaster with ilike '%pattern%' - try FTS with gin index and `HERE (data ->> 'product_info')  && pattern`

Comment: You should have look at [trigram indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13452528/479863) to speed up LIKE queries.

Comment: @muistooshort already have: CREATE INDEX words_trgm_gin
  ON public.fsa_raw
  USING gin
  ((data ->> 'product_info'::text) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" gin_trgm_ops);

Comment: Right, sorry, missed that scrollbar.